# Excel VBA: get specific table data from html table

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping

I'm trying to pull the main data table from this website using innerhtml and then looping through but I get bunch of different table data and just a mess (tried webquerytable but the format I get isn't right for me)
http://lcvpd.lt/lt/aktualijos/statistika/uzbsands.php

Is there a way to extract only the main data table?

Sorry for bad communication, I am new to vba and don't know how to correctly explain the sitaution.

Here's where I am so far:

```
Sub HTML_Table_To_Excel()

    Dim htm As Object
    Dim Tr As Object
    Dim Td As Object
    Dim Tab1 As Object

    'Replace the URL of the webpage that you want to download
    Web_URL = VBA.Trim(Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1))

    'Create HTMLFile Object
    Set HTML_Content = CreateObject("htmlfile")

    'Get the WebPage Content to HTMLFile Object
    With CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp")
        .Open "GET", Web_URL, False
        .send
        HTML_Content.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    Column_Num_To_Start = 1
    iRow = 2
    iCol = Column_Num_To_Start
    iTable = 10

    'Loop Through Each Table and Download it to Excel in Proper Format
    For Each Tab1 In HTML_Content.getElementsByTagName("table")
        With HTML_Content.getElementsByTagName("table")(iTable)
            For Each Tr In .Rows
                For Each Td In Tr.Cells
                    Sheets(1).Cells(iRow, iCol).Select
                    Sheets(1).Cells(iRow, iCol) = Td.innerText
                    iCol = iCol + 1
                Next Td
                iCol = Column_Num_To_Start
                iRow = iRow + 1
            Next Tr
        End With
        iTable = iTable + 1
        iCol = Column_Num_To_Start
        iRow = iRow + 1
    Next Tab1
End Sub
```

Comment: show us what you have tried so far

Comment: @Ken updated post

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the elements by its tag names, wich is very generic. If your table does not have an specific id or class and you call it by its tag name, it will pull all the elements with that tag name (or even the ones with other names). I'm having some similar problems trying to retrieve specific table data right in the middle of a web page. Wish i could consult the data base, instead of getting html elements inner texts.